# A lot of jitter when running a torrent client

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I've been running into an issue that is making me tear my hairs out. In my network, whenever I run a torrent my network clogs up. I experience packet loss and a very high ping. I've limited the bandwidth (both up and down) to around 40% of the maximum speed. I've capped the total maximum allowed connections at 10 which didn't make much difference either. I haven't a clue as to what might be causing this.

**My home network:**

I have a modem provided by my ISP in bridge mode connected to a Unifi Dream Machine (Gateway). The rest of the network is either connected to a Unifi switch or access point.

The problem happens on both a Raspberry Pi and my own host. To eliminate a fault in my local network I've tried the following while a torrent was running:

1. Ping the Cloudflare DNS (normally 10ms during torrenting it shoots up to 600ms)
2. Ping the Dream Machine from the same host (stays low at around 0.15ms even while torrenting)
3. Running iperf3 across my network Dream Machine to host. The throughput is a steady 1Gb/s.
4. I mirrored the traffic going out and captured it with Wireshark, the number of TCP errors rises from about 10 errors/s to about 225 errors/s. I get a lot of `[TCP ACKed unseen segment]` messages while torrenting. Not limited to the torrenting host but also the rest of the network.
5. I've tried it with multiple clients (Transmission, Deluge and Qbittorrent).
6. I've tried multiple hosts
7. I've tried running the traffic through a VPN but that doesn't seem to change much.
8. Changed the cable connecting the Dream Machine to the modem.

The only notable difference I found out was that when I'm running a torrent client on my PC it only causes jitter in the beginning and when it settles around 50 connections it goes back to normal with the occasional peak. When it's running on my Raspberry Pi the jitter is quite steady and only occasionally goes back to normal.

It happens regardless of the speed of the torrents, it stops once I pause the torrents.

Does anyone have an idea as to what it might be or what I can try at this point to troubleshoot this more?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like it may be buffer bloat, google some buffer bloat tests and see what the results come out as.

Comment: Interesting, never heard of that. I ran the test a couple of times however and both the website I used and the ping commando I had running in the background don't suggest that it's buffer bloat.

Comment: And what happens when you enable QOS on the dream machine? Put http/https as a higher priority than the port being used for your torrent client, it should help.

Comment: I've enabled smart queues, which is the UDM's way of prioritizing traffic. It doesn't seem to affect the problem however.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect my ISP's modem or the connection to my house. So I'll call up my ISP to put it back into normal mode and check if my modem itself has this problem too.